# Angular-cli environments.ts override

Tags: angular-cli

I have an angular-cli project and custom library imported into it.
like, "import { NewModule } from 'new-library';"

This library has an own environments.ts file.

So the question is:

*How I can override variables defined in environments.ts inside library?*

Because, for now "NewModule" refered to localhost

```
export const environment = {
      production: false,
      baseUrl: "localhost:8080/api"
```

but I need that the module will refering to "myhost.com"

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: "myhost.com:8080/api"
```

And I don't have an access to code in "new-library".

Comment: Talk to whoever has access to the code in the library, and ask them how to do this. Without knowing more about the library, we cannot help you. All we can do is guess.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
That means if I just define baseUrl variable in my local file "environment.ts"
it will not override baseUrl in imported library automatically. 
Am I right?

Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with Angular and maybe Angular has a build-in mechanism for this which I don't know about.